# Swift 4 - Resizing Navigation Buttons Programatically

Tags: ios, swift, menu, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm not using storyboards and need to know how to resize and reposition the left bar button. The image I'm using is too big and not far enough to the left.

```
let leftBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: (image), landscapeImagePhone: (image), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarItem
```

This code makes this -

[image]

But I need it to look like this -

[image]

I would rather not go back and resize the actual image in Photoshop. What are my options? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look @ this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048852/how-can-i-set-size-leftbarbuttonitem/48049103#48049103

Comment: You're a life saver. That did it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876060/how-to-add-custom-view-on-right-of-navigation-bar-swift

Comment: @brianwantsblood : am glad I could be of help :) happy coding :) consider up voting the answer if u think that was helpful :) cheers